# Как проверить программу на аварийное закрытие?

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю OPC клиент на winforms, который подключается к специальному серверу и считывает с него данные по этому протоколу.

Проблема заключается вот в том, что если программа аварийно закрывается по каким-либо причинам, или если завершить ее самому через диспетчер задач, то соединение с сервером все еще остается, что не есть хорошо. В связи с этим возник вопрос: можно ли как-то в самой программе проверять завершилась она корректна или нет, И если нет, то уже вызывать disconnect?

Comment: Как делал я: Просто посылайте от сервера "пустой" запрос раз в 1-2 минуты.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Но дело в том, что если моя прога завершилась аварийно, то она уже не считывает данные, как таковые и я не могу ею управлять. Соединение как бы просто висит

Comment: Вы не поняли, если прога "завершилась", то на стороне клиента уже связи нет, это сервер "думает" что она есть, и серверу нужно переодически опрашивать эти соединения на предмет их существования.

Comment: Аа, вот оно что. А не подскажете, как можно так сделать ? Вы случайно не работали с MatrikonOPC server ?

Comment: Нет не работал, используйте таймер. по таймеру шлите "пустые" запросы на все клиенты. Неактивные клиенты при отправке выдадут исключения, или их `IsConnection` станет `False`. Это уже по ситуации смотрите.

Comment: Кажется понял. Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

Если программа аварийно завершилась - то сама она ничего сделать не сможет точно.

В понятие "аварийное завершение" входит, к примеру, выключение света. Вы что, ищите способы продолжить работу программы без электричества? :)

Ваш сервер должен сам определять "повисшие" соединения и отключать их по тайм-ауту.

Comment: Да, действительно :) Спасибо, попробую покопаться с самим сервером